# Create complex json objects using gson

Tags: java, json, gson, javabeans

How to create javabean for `gson` for the below JSON script?

```
{
    "header": [
        {
            "title": {
                "attempts": 3,
                "required": true
            }
        },
        {
            "on": {
                "next": "abcd",
                "event": "continue"
            }
        },
        {
            "on": {
                "next": "",
                "event": "break"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I'm trying to build the javabean for this JSON output. I'm not able to repeat the fieldname `on`.

Please suggest any solutions.

Comment: Ok, what is your question ?

Comment: i want to build the above json script through gson. For this i am not able to create the java bean

Comment: i am getting the error multiple field name with "no"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need multiple classes to accomplish this. I made some assumptions with the naming, but these should suffice:

```
public class Response {
    private List<Entry> header;

    private class Entry {
        private Title title;
        private On on;
    }

    private class Title {
        int attempts;
        boolean required;
    }

    private class On {
        String next, event;
    }
}
```

You can test it with a `main()` method like:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // The JSON from your post
    String json = "{\"header\":[{\"title\":{\"attempts\":3,\"required\":true}},{\"on\":{\"next\":\"abcd\",\"event\":\"continue\"}},{\"on\":{\"next\":\"\",\"event\":\"break\"}}]}";

    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();
    Response response = gson.fromJson(json, Response.class);

    System.out.println(response.header.get(0).title.attempts); // 3
    System.out.println(response.header.get(1).on.next); // abcd
    System.out.println(gson.toJson(response)); // Produces the exact same JSON as the original
}
```